# finding basis and dimension for given kernel and Im

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

let F be a field with 5 objects.
$T:F_3[x] -> F_3[x]$ is a linear transformation given by the following matrice: $[T]_{B} =   \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 0 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix} $ 
    with regards to the given basis $B=(1,1+x,1+x+x^2)$

a)find a basis and dimension for kerT and ImT.

b)calculate $T(ax^2+bx+c)$

i tried and couldn't find any relation or dependency in regards to the basis which will allow me to calculate the basis and dimension for given kerT and imT.
can you please help me with that?
I became desperate with this question. been trying it for a week.

Comment: Hint: Write the canonical basis above your matrix, then use elementary row/column transformations on both matrices simultaneously.

Comment: first you say $F$ has $5$ objects, then you say $F_3\to F_3.$  Is that what you mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you mean $T:F_5\to F_5$

$[T]_{B} =   \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 0 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

There is no need to change basis yet.  We can find the kernel in terms of the basis B

Based on the locations of the zeros in the first and second columns, we can quickly make a guess at what the kernel must be.

$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$

$[T]_{B} =   \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 0 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf 0$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$
span the image.

However this kernel and span is relative to the basis $B.$

In the standard basis.

The kernel:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix} = 1+3(1+x) + (1+x+x^2) = 0+4x + x^2$

We could also use this technique.

The image:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2&3\\1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

b)

$a x^2 + bx + c$

Covert to basis B.

$a (x^2 + x + 1) + (b-a) (x+1) + (c-b)$

$T[\langle c-b,b-a, a\rangle ] = \langle c+b+a,c-b+4a,b+a \rangle$

$c+b+a + (c-b+4a)(x+1) + (b+a)(x^2+x+1) = 6a+b+2c + (c+5a)x + (b+a)x^2$

but we are in $F_5$

$a+b+2c + (c)x + (b+a)x^2$

Or you could say:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\1&0&4\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&0\\0&1&-1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c\\b\\a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c\\b\\a\end{bmatrix}$

$(a+b)x^2 + cx + a+b+2c$

Comment: how do i calculate $T(ax^2+bx+c)$?

Comment: Redone vs yesterday